# Stable marriage in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I implemented a [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) in Haskell few month ago. It's not optimized at all and I'd like to know how to make it better from performance and readability perspective.

```
data Sex = Male | Female deriving (Eq, Show)
data Virtue = Intelligence | Appearence | Kindness deriving (Eq, Show, Enum)

data Parameter = Parameter{
    virtue :: Virtue,
    value :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

data Person = Person{
    name :: String,
    sex :: Sex,
    preferences :: [Virtue],
    parameters :: [Parameter],
    partner :: Maybe Person
} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Results list of women sorted by preferences of one man by `defaultRateFunction :: Person -> Person -> Int`. In my implementation it depends on judges `preferences` and rated person `parameters`. I won't put it there for brevity. You can find full program in a link to Gist at the bottom of post. Imagine that function to be anything you want.

```
personalRating :: Person -> [Person] -> [Person]
personalRating x ys = sortBy (comparing (\y -> defaultRateFunction x y)) ys
```

Man makes an engagement proposal for the woman and if she don't have partner — she replies positively (`True`) and if she does, if new partner's rating > than the old one's — "returns" `True` and if it does not — `False`

```
proposal :: Person -> Person -> Bool
proposal male female
    | isNothing (partner female) = True
    | defaultRateFunction female male > defaultRateFunction female (fromJust $ partner female) = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Man makes a proposal for each woman in females untill he'll find the one who'll reply positively. Assumed that there are at least one of this type in the array

```
findTheBride :: Person -> [Person] -> Person
findTheBride male females 
    | proposal male (head females) == True = head females
    | otherwise = findTheBride male (tail females)
```

The ugliest part is marrige algorhitm itself. As I call it recursively I have to clean person from array of corresponded sexes every time it finds partner and also check if woman has an ex-partner, and deal with thier "breakup" also.

```
marrige :: [Person] -> [Person] -> [Person]
marrige males females
        | sm == [] = females
        | isNothing ex = marrige
            (fsmWithNewPartner:(delete fsm males))
            (fsmPartnerWithFsm:(delete fsmPartner females))
        | otherwise = marrige 
            (fsmWithNewPartner:((fromJust ex) {partner = Nothing}):(delete fsm $ delete (fromJust ex) males))
            (fsmPartnerWithFsm:(delete fsmPartner females))
    where 
        sm = filter (\x -> partner x == Nothing) males -- Single males
        fsm = head sm -- Fist single male
        fsmPartner = findTheBride fsm (personalRating fsm females) -- Fist single male's partner
        ex = partner fsmPartner -- Partner's ex (Maybe)
        fsmWithNewPartner = fsm {partner = Just fsmPartner}
        fsmPartnerWithFsm = fsmPartner {partner = Just fsm}
```

Full version of program (where random Person data are generated) avialible on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/altjsus/8ca2f0b8cd771a5e7a7ae3bdefb83a23).

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake: marrige = marriage. I'm not native in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Safe (findJust)
import Data.Foldable (null, all)

personalRating = sortBy . comparing . defaultRateFunction

proposal m f = all (on (>) (defaultRateFunction f) m) $ partner f

remarry p x = (x {partner = p} :) . delete x

marrige :: [Person] -> [Person] -> [Person]
marrige ms fs = case find (null . partner) ms of
  Nothing -> fs
  Just m -> marrige
    (remarry (Just f} m $ maybe id (remarry Nothing) (partner f) ms)
    (remarry (Just m) f fs)
    where f = findJust (proposal m) $ personalRating m fs
```

You never actually use `ms` that have a partner. Why keep track of them? I'll assume that all start out without partners, otherwise filter once at the start. In particular, I'll assume the invariant that partnership is symmetric.

```
marrige :: [Person] -> [Person] -> [Person]
marrige [] fs = fs
marriage (m:ms) fs = marrige 
  (maybe id (\ex -> (ex {partner = Nothing} :)) (partner f) ms)
  (f {partner = Just m} : delete f fs)
    where f = findJust (proposal m) $ personalRating m fs
```

For performance, you could use `Data.Map` instead of `[]`'s `delete`.

Edit: Here's one where the explicit recursion is less global. Unsetting `ex`'s partner may be superfluous.

```
import Control.Monad.State

marrige = execState . traverse_ go where go m = do
  f <- gets $ findJust (proposal m) . personalRating m
  modify $ (f {partner = Just m} :) . delete f
  for_ (partner f) $ \ex -> go $ ex {partner = Nothing}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to mark your answer. I'd like to know if `marriage` could be more syntax-sweet.

Comment: If you're not satisfied, we needn't be done! Specify what metric you'd like to improve. For example, with another data structure and using the `lens` library, the penultimate line could be `at f ?= m`.